# Excluding exaclty two numbers from being typed in a TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i want to exclude two numbers "3 and 4" from being typed in a TextField, i tried:

```
var theTextField:TextField = new TextField();
theTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
theTextField.border = true;
theTextField.x = 10;
theTextField.y = 10;
addChild(theTextField);

theTextField.restrict="0-9^3-4";
```

this successfuly excludes 3 & 4 from being typed in the textfield but it also prevent you from typing 33 or 45 for example, i only want to exclude 3 and 4. Any number with two or three digits that contains 3 or 4 should be allowed, any idea how can i do this?

Comment: How would you even be able to type 33 into the textfield if you don't allow the user to type in 3 (other than copy paste)? You can't have both at the same time unless you evaluate the content of the textfield afterwards, instead of preventing the character completely.

Comment: Put a runtime validation (**Event.CHANGE** from your **TextField**) and display a warning (like a red line above) if the **TextField** contains an invalid entry.

Answer (score 0):

So to restrict combinations 34 and 43 only?

Like Organis commented, you should validate the input via `Event.CHANGE` and if you already haven't let user to know about the restriction, show a warning of a somekind.

Insided the validation function you can check if the input text is "34" or "43" and then remove the second character from it to simulate the actual restriction:

```
theTextField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, validateInput);

function validateInput(e:Event):void{
    if(e.target.text == "34" || e.target.text == "43"){
        e.target.text = e.target.text.split("")[0];
    }
}
```

You could also use RegExp to check the match, and `.slice` instead of `.split` inside the function:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /^[34|43]{2}$/;
if(pattern.test(e.target.text)){
    e.target.text = e.target.text.slice(0,-1);
}
```

And if you're going to end up with more complex restriction patterns, with `.split` you can build more complex checks by checking the `n`th character and so on:

```
if(e.target.text.length == 2){
    if((e.target.text.split("")[0] == "3" && e.target.text.split("")[1] == "4") ||
        (e.target.text.split("")[0] == "4" && e.target.text.split("")[1] == "3")){
            e.target.text = e.target.text.slice(0,-1);
        }
}
```